# run node from .desktop file

Tags: node.js, linux, angular, desktop-application

Hi I'm tryng to run an application by double click it in linux and I've read about .desktop file (I need to open by doble click because I've got to deploy the app on a Raspberry and users don't want to use terminal).
This is what I've done so far:

**desktop file:**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=CHRONOTERMOSTAT
Icon=../../../../../../home/gjcode/Scaricati/icons8-automazione-riscaldamento-48.png
Exec=sudo "../../../../../../home/gjcode/WebstormProjects/tlc-app/scripts/runAngular" %f
Exec="../../../../../../home/gjcode/WebstormProjects/tlc-app/scripts/runNode" %f
Exec="../../../../../../home/gjcode/WebstormProjects/tlc-app/scripts/openBrowser" %f
Comment=A chronotermostat for home automation
Categories=Application
Terminal=true
```

**runAngular:**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ../ui
ng serve
```

**runNode:**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ../broker
npm start
```

**openBrowser:**

```
#!/bin/bash

google-chrome http://localhost:4200
```

I'm running these files on ubuntu so I don't actually need to run angular on Raspberry, but I have to run node server. When I double click the browser is opened but none of node and angular seems to be started. When I run these scripts by a terminal everything work well. I've checked running permissions and everything is ok:

```
4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 gjcode gjcode  49 lug  3 16:35 openBrowser
4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 gjcode gjcode  31 lug  3 16:34 runAngular
4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 gjcode gjcode  36 lug  3 16:59 runNode
```

I've tested this approach by running a simple script and everything worked fine, so what am I doing wrong? How to double click and run node and open the browser?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe just the last Exec gets executed? Have you tried to keep one Exec and pipe the commands with `&&`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it on my own, and it was a problem with the path, for anyone who will face the same issue remember that **EXEC use**: `home/username` as a working directory even though you put the file in `usr/share/applications` so change the path accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means in practice. I have the same problem and I'm using absolute paths in the .desktop file, which says `Exec=/home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor/start.sh`.